# Iteratively draw and connect nodes via `\foreach`

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the (currently incorrect) MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]

\def\mypoints{(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)};
\def\lastnode{(1,0)};
\foreach \x in \mypoints { 
    \draw[fill] \x circle (0.05);   
    \path[draw, -latex', black!50!white] \x -| \lastnode;
    \let\lastnode=\x;
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to iterate through a list of points, either defined as such or generated through a `\foreach` range, and draw a circle/node/rectangle/etc at each point and then draw an arrow or other line to that point from the previous iteration.

What I thought would work is to create a `trailer` variable that maintains the state of the most recently drawn node, then use that information to draw the connecting lines easily. Currently the `\lastnode` variable is not updating, most likely because I am using the wrong macro for the job...

Is it possible to use the above outlined method to draw and connect nodes/points/... iteratively, or is another approach more appropriate? Ideally, the solution would work with both points `(x, y)` and named nodes `(nodenumber1)`.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. I have located it in the manual, the remember option works like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example defines nodes `node1`, `node2`, ... and draw edges between them. The option `remember` for `\foreach` allows to save some values from the previous loop pass.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]

\def\mypoints{%
  (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0),
  (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)%
};
\path
  \foreach \x [count=\xi] in \mypoints {
    \x node[circle, fill, inner sep=sqrt(2)*0.025cm] (node\xi) {}
  }
  \foreach \x [count=\xi, remember=\xi-1 as \xiprev] in \mypoints {
    \ifnum\xi>1 %
      (node\xiprev) edge[-latex', black!50!white] (node\xi)
    \fi
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]