# In Tikz, how to write equations on the top of foreach arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

May you provide some guidance on how to add some descriptions on the arrow of the following two figures?
For example,

#### In the first figure,

- can we add: `Arrow $\vec{21}$` on the top of arrow (better to be (1) **parallel** or (2) **horizontal** if possible, but not necessary if it is too difficult for you)  from the item 2 to the item 1?
- Similarly, can we add: `Arrow $\vec{i j}$` on the top of each arrow from the item `i` to the item `j`? Here `i=2`, and `j=1,3,4,5,6`.

#### In the second figure,

- can we try to add some greek alphabet, `$\alpha$`, `$\beta$`, `$\gamma$`, etc on each of the arrow?

Can we make the above alignment to have the choices of being (1) **parallel** to the arrow or (2) **horizontal** to the document? If so, could you advise the command lines for each case?

[image]

Here is my Minimal Working note MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,slashed,mathtools,tabu}


\begin{document}


\newline

\;\;\;\;
\begin{tikzpicture}\kern-5mm[>=stealth,->,shorten >=2pt,looseness=.5,auto]
      \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=8mm]{
1 & 2 & 3\\
   4    &  5 & 6 \\
   };
       \foreach \a/\b in {1-2/2-1,1-2/1-1,1-2/2-2,1-2/2-3, 1-2/1-3}
{\draw[thick,->](M-\a)--(M-\b);}
    \end{tikzpicture}



\newline

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]

\def\mypoints{%
  (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0),
  (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)%
};
\path
  \foreach \x [count=\xi] in \mypoints {
    \x node[circle, fill, inner sep=sqrt(2)*0.025cm] (node\xi) {}
  }
  \foreach \x [count=\xi, remember=\xi-1 as \xiprev] in \mypoints {
    \ifnum\xi>1 %
      (node\xiprev) edge[-latex', black!50!white] (node\xi)
    \fi
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

The second figure is from and many thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385800/41144

Comment: As I understand it, you want each arrow to have an equation written next to it and that equation to be parallel to the arrow. Is that correct?
If not, can you add a freehand drawing of the desired result?

Comment: Dear AndreC, the attempt output of the user is good (but I am not sure the file is compilable...)

Comment: (maybe you can try to compile of user213378 file and you will see the issue...) thank you!

Comment: It can be compiled with asymptote as it gave the code, otherwise, with LaTeX, you have to add `\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}` and compile successively this way `pdflatex->asymptote->pdflatex`.

Comment: I added \usepackage[inline]{asymptote} in the beginning but not working...

Comment: look here and use `\begin{asy}` [Using Asymptote with pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/using-asymptote-with-pdflatex)

Answer (score 3):

TikZ can probably do it !

While waiting for an TikZ answer, I have an Asymptote answer as following:

Only for compare purpose!

```
usepackage("esvect");
picture pic1,pic2;

size(pic1,8cm);
pair[] A={(0,0),(-1,0),(1,0),sqrt(2)*dir(-135),(0,-1),sqrt(2)*dir(-45)};
int[] B={2,1,3,4,5,6};
margin m=Margin(2.5,2.5);
for (int i=0; i< A.length; ++i){  label(pic1,"$"+ (string) B[i] + "$",A[i],(0,0)); }
draw(pic1,Label("$\vv{21}$"),A[0]--A[1],Arrow,m);
draw(pic1,Label("$\vv{23}$",LeftSide),A[0]--A[2],Arrow,m);
draw(pic1,rotate(degrees(dir(A[0]-A[3])))*Label("$\vv{24}$"),A[0]--A[3],Arrow,m);
draw(pic1,rotate(degrees(dir(A[0]-A[4])))*Label("$\vv{25}$"),A[0]--A[4],Arrow,m);
draw(pic1,rotate(degrees(dir(A[5]-A[0])))*Label("$\vv{26}$",LeftSide),A[0]--A[5],Arrow,m);

size(pic2,10cm);
pair[] A={(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1),(0,1)};
string[] alphabet={"$\alpha$", "$\beta$", "$\gamma$"};
alphabet.cyclic=true;
dot(pic2,A);
for (int i=0; i< A.length-1; ++i){
  draw(pic2,scale(0.8)*alphabet[i],A[i]--A[i+1],Arrow,Margin(1,1));
}
picture pic;
add(pic,pic1.fit(),(0,0),N);
add(pic,pic2.fit(),(0,0),S);
add(pic);
shipout(bbox(pic,2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I think he means alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon, which is the Greek alphabet.

Comment: That is not a problem, +1 - I think this is already a great nearly perfect answer!

Comment: excuse me, however, how do we use usepackage("esvect"); and why not \usepackage("esvect"); ???

Comment: @wonderich You can see here https://www.overleaf.com/6581438472kbmkvdwtwbvk

Comment: @wonderich To answer for why do we use `usepackage("esvect");`, see page 53 of the official documetation.

Answer (score 2):

With TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains, 
                matrix,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
       every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=2pt, sloped}
                        ] 
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={circle, minimum size=1.1em, inner sep=1pt, anchor=center},
             column sep=2cm,
             row sep=2cm]
{
1 & 2 & 3     \\
4 & 5 & 6     \\
};
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {1/1/1, 4/2/1, 5/2/2, 6/2/3, 3/1/3}
{
\draw   (m-1-2) edge ["$\vv{21}$"] (m-\j-\k);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
       

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 2cm and 2 cm,
             start chain = going right,
              dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt},
       every edge/.style = {draw=gray, thick, -Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=2pt, sloped}
                        ]

  \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{
    \node (n1\i) [dot, on chain] {};
    \node (n2\i) [dot, above=of n1\i] {};
}
  \foreach \x [count=\xi,count=\xj from 2] in {\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \alpha}
\ifnum\xj<6     \draw (n1\xi) edge["$\x$"] (n1\xj);   \fi
  \foreach \x [count=\xi,count=\xj from 2] in {\gamma, \beta, \alpha,  \gamma}
\ifnum\xj<6     \draw (n2\xj) edge["$\x$"] (n2\xi);   \fi
\draw (n15) edge["$\beta$"] (n25);
 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks! this looks nearly perfect!!! I am learning it. ++1